# Split string line read by a batch file

Tags: scripting, batch

is there a way to "split" the value of string line readed by a batch file ?
Suppose to have this text file

192.168.1.2; PC_NAME_1

192.168.1.3; PC_NAME_3

...

I would like to read line 1, and split the value into two variables ... So i can use IP address, and also, Pc Name (for other purpose)... for example:

> for /f %%x in (txtfile.txt) do (
>   ....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. A special FOR syntax is used

```
for /F "delims=," %A in (filename.txt) do call subbatch.bat %A %B %C %D %E
```

That'll split it just on a comma. But by default it'll split on space and tab. the 'tokens' term can specify how many of those you want to deal with

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,*" %A in (filename.txt) do call subbatch.bat %A %B %C "%D"
```

In this case %D will contain everything from the fourth delim and beyond.

The thing to keep in mind, though, is that "Do" is not a procedure block, it's a one-off call. This is where "goto" or "call" can be used to invoke further logic. My examples above call another batch-file and pass in the needed parameters as command-line options, so for those subbatch files the variables will be on %1 and %2.

Comment: You can also start a block with an opening parenthesis after the `do`.

Comment: You should not use `goto` after `DO` or it will break the loop. You are correct about using Call though. @Joey You are correct about using `( <code> )` after the DO block as long as the `(` starts on the same line right after the `DO`. You can also `CALL :label` to run a sub-procedure within the same batch file.